# Custom modal view controller looks odd after dismissing MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Here is my code which i have used, but when i return from mail compose controller my previous modal view controller size get reduced. i am not able to find where to set controller size so it make effect on presenting view controller.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{

switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
        break;
}

// Remove the mail view

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 30, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
```

}

Comment: try to set the size at -(void)viewWillAppear method

Comment: @Sushrita-  already tried this thing but din't get desired output.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the problem is?

Comment: i have a modal view controller with customised  frame size . On a particular screen i have to use MFMailViewController. Till now every thing works fine but when i use dismissViewControllerAnimated method to dissmiss mail view controller. My screen size get reduced. i tried to change its size explicitly but dint get succeed.

Comment: Are you using .xib or storyboard?

Comment: sorry I have not much idea about .xib

Comment: I have given below the answer please have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a silly mistake. Now i want to close this question thats why i am posting answer after so long time.

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 30, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
```

I just had to fix this line as every time it will reduce its width and size. This was my beginning in iOS ;)